# lua tables - allowed values and syntax

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

I need a Lua table for a wireshark dissector:

```
table xref = {
5123336196=7423345345
}
```

This is clearly not allowed, although I'm not sure why based on the LUA documentation.

How do I implement a table crossing large integers to other large integers?

Comment: `[5123336196]=7423345345`  In Lua 5.1 and 5.2 numbers are limited by `2^53`

Comment: ah, yes.  Please answer so I can mark it !  thanks