# lua tables - string representation

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

as a followup question to [lua tables - allowed values and syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687123/lua-tables-allowed-values-and-syntax):

I need a table that equates large numbers to strings.  The catch seems to be that strings with punctuation are not allowed:

```
local Names = {
   [7022003001] = fulsom jct, OH
   [7022003002] = kennedy center, NY
}
```

but neither are quotes:

```
local Names = {
   [7022003001] = "fulsom jct, OH"
   [7022003002] = "kennedy center, NY"
}
```

I have even tried without any spaces:

```
local Names = {
   [7022003001] = fulsomjctOH
   [7022003002] = kennedycenterNY
}
```

When this module is loaded, wireshark complains "}" is expected to close "{" at line . How can I implement a table with a string that contains spaces and punctuation?

Comment: Why do you say that quotes aren't allowed?

Comment: You need a comma between the items, that is, before `[7022003002]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Lua Reference Manual - 3.1 - Lexical Conventions](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.1):

> A short literal string can be delimited by matching single or double quotes, and can contain the (...) C-like escape sequences (...).

That means the short literal string in Lua is:

```lua
local foo = "I'm a string literal"
```

This matches your second example. The reason why it fails is because it lacks a separator between table members:

```lua
local Names = {
   [7022003001] = "fulsom jct, OH",
   [7022003002] = "kennedy center, NY"
}
```

You can also add a trailing separator after the last member.

The more detailed description of the table constructor can be found in [3.4.9 - Table Constructors](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9). It could be summed up by the example provided there:

> ```lua
> a = { [f(1)] = g; "x", "y"; x = 1, f(x), [30] = 23; 45 }
> ```

I really, really recommend using the Lua Reference Manual, it is an amazing helper.

I also highly encourage you to read some basic tutorials e.g. [Learn Lua in 15 minutes](http://tylerneylon.com/a/learn-lua/). They should give you an overview of the language you are trying to use.